# 2 Player Battleship with Multiple Ships

Tags: python, python-3.x, community-challenge

This is it. My best game, a fully functional, 2 player game of battleship.

- My coordinate picker can be seen [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/155049/battleship-coordinate-picker). I didn't make all the changes they wanted.
- I would prefer some insight on whether I should make a `board` class
- The `skilstak.colors` library, is also called `solarized` and can be found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/solarized/1.2.5).

  - `c.cl`=`clear`,`c.g`=`green`,`c.m`=`magenta`,`c.y`=`yellow`,`c.x`=`reset`,`c.r`=`red`
- I don't really care if you add any `"grammar"` `PEP8` violations
- I made it so you can easily add ships or change the size, but haven't added it yet.
- Edit: I keep updating it, so you can follow along [here](https://github.com/reteps/pyship/blob/master/pyship).

Constants / Imports

```
from operator import itemgetter
import getch
import skilstak.colors as c #colors
BOARD_LENGTH = 10
BOARD_HEIGHT = 10
LETTERS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$'
INFO = 'use WASD to move, and r to rotate your ship. Press q to quit and enter to confirm your selection.'
ACTION_KEYS = {
    'w':'UP',
    's':'DOWN',
    'd':'RIGHT',
    'a':'LEFT',
}
```

The library

```
class Ship:
    def __init__(self, size, symbol):
        self.size = size
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.coords = [(x,0) for x in range(size)]
        self.previous_coords = [(None,None) for _ in range(size)]
    def shift(self,direction): #moves the ships coordinates

        x_values = list(map(itemgetter(0), self.coords))
        y_values = list(map(itemgetter(1), self.coords))
        if direction == 'LEFT' and 0 not in x_values:
            change = (-1,0)
        elif direction == 'DOWN' and BOARD_HEIGHT-1 not in y_values:
            change = (0,1)
        elif direction == 'UP' and 0 not in y_values:
            change = (0,-1)
        elif direction == 'RIGHT' and BOARD_LENGTH-1 not in x_values:
            change = (1,0)    
        else:
            change = (0,0)
        for i, coord in enumerate(self.coords):
            self.previous_coords[i] = self.coords[i] 
            self.coords[i] = (coord[0] + change[0], coord[1] + change[1])

    def rotate(self): #90 degree clockwise rotation
        a, b = self.coords[0][0], self.coords[0][1]
        x, y = self.coords[-1][0], self.coords[-1][1] 
        newx, newy = -(y-b)+a, (x-a)+b
        if newy >= 0 and newx >= 0 and newy <= BOARD_HEIGHT-1 and newx <= BOARD_LENGTH-1:
            for i, coord in enumerate(self.coords):
                self.previous_coords[i] = self.coords[i]
                self.coords[i] = (-(self.coords[i][1]-b)+a, (self.coords[i][0]-a)+b)

    def show(self, foreground,background, hasprevious=True): 
        if hasprevious: #erases the previous cells, draws the new cells
            for pcoord in self.previous_coords:
                foreground[pcoord[1]][pcoord[0]] = None
        for coord in self.coords:
            foreground[coord[1]][coord[0]] = self.symbol
        list_display = []
        for rowi in range(BOARD_HEIGHT): #displays the foreground or background depending on if there is a foreground
            row = ''
            for chari in range(BOARD_LENGTH):
                if foreground[rowi][chari] == None:
                    char = background[rowi][chari]
                else:
                    char = foreground[rowi][chari]
                row += char + ' '
            list_display.append(row)
        display_board = '\n'.join(list_display)
        print(c.clear + display_board)
        return foreground

def choose_locations():
    ships = [Ship(5,'A'),Ship(4,'B'),Ship(3,'c'),Ship(3,'C'),Ship(2,'D')] 
    finalcoords = []
    flatcoords = []
    background = [['_'] * BOARD_LENGTH for _ in range(BOARD_HEIGHT)]
    foreground = [[None] * BOARD_LENGTH for _ in range(BOARD_HEIGHT)] 
    for ship in ships:
        foreground = ship.show(foreground,background,hasprevious=False)
        while True:
            key = getch.getch()
            if key in ACTION_KEYS:
                ship.shift(ACTION_KEYS[key]) 
                foreground = ship.show(foreground,background)
            elif key == 'r':
                ship.rotate()
                foreground = ship.show(foreground,background)
            elif key == 'q':
                exit()
            elif key == '\r': #enter

                intersection = list(set(ship.coords).intersection(flatcoords))
                if not intersection:
                    finalcoords.append(ship.coords)
                    flatcoords += ship.coords
                    for coord in ship.coords:
                        foreground[coord[1]][coord[0]] = None
                        background[coord[1]][coord[0]] = ship.symbol
                    break
                else:
                    print('''You already have a ship or part of a ship there.Your current coordinates are {}
You have placed a ship on these coords, {}. 
You overlapped on these coords: {}'''.format(ship.coords,flatcoords,intersection))
            else:
                print(INFO)

    foreground = ships[-1].show(foreground,background)    
    return finalcoords
def display(board):

    side_col = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30] 
    print('   ' + ' '.join(LETTERS[:len(board[0])]))
    for i, row in enumerate(board):
        print(str(side_col[i]) + ('  ' if side_col[i] < 10 else ' ') + ' '.join(row))

def pick_cell(board):
    while True:
        raw = input('Aim a missile at ' + c.y)
        print(c.x)
        if len(raw) < 2 or len(raw) > 3:
            print(c.r + 'Invalid Coordinates' + c.x)
            continue
        rawx, rawy = raw[0], raw[1:]
        try:
            cell = LETTERS.index(rawx.upper())
        except ValueError:
            print(c.r + 'Invalid Letter' + c.x)
            continue
        try:
            row = int(rawy) - 1
            if row >= BOARD_HEIGHT:
                print(c.r + 'Invalid Number' + c.x)
                continue
        except ValueError:
            print(c.r + 'Invalid Row' + c.x)
            continue
        if board[row][cell] == c.r + 'X' + c.x or board[row][cell] == c.c + 'O' + c.x:
            print(c.r + 'You already picked this location!' + c.x)
            continue
        else:
            break

    return (cell,row)
def check_coords(board, coords):
    for coord in coords:
        if board[coord[1]][coord[0]] != c.r + 'X' + c.x:
            return False
    return True
def place_cell(board, target, ship_locations):
    hit = False
    for i,ship_coords in enumerate(ship_locations):
        for j,coord in enumerate(ship_coords):
            if coord == target:
                board[target[1]][target[0]] = c.r + 'X' + c.x

                if check_coords(board, ship_coords):
                    del ship_locations[i]
                    length = len(ship_locations) 
                    print('{}You sunk one of my ships! There is {} ships left{}.'.format(c.m,length,c.x))
                    if length == 0:
                        print('You win!')
                        exit()
                else: 
                    print(c.m + 'You hit my ship!' + c.x)
                hit = True
    if not hit:
        print(c.m + 'You missed!' + c.x)
        board[target[1]][target[0]] = c.c + 'O' + c.x
    return board, ship_locations
```

The game

```
if __name__ == '__main__':                
    try:
        input(c.cl + 'Player 1, choose your locations [W/A/S/D to move, R to rotate and enter to confirm]\n(enter to continue)\n')
        p1_ship_locations = choose_locations()
        input(c.cl + 'Player 2, choose your locations [W/A/S/D to move, R to rotate and enter to confirm]\n(enter to continue)\n')
        p2_ship_locations = choose_locations()
        p1_board = [['_'] * BOARD_LENGTH for _ in range(BOARD_HEIGHT)]
        p2_board = [['_'] * BOARD_LENGTH for _ in range(BOARD_HEIGHT)]
        print(c.cl)
        while True:
            #player 1
            input(c.cl + "Player 1, it's your turn (enter to continue)\n")
            display(p2_board)
            print('\nYour Board\n')
            display(p1_board)
            p1_location = pick_cell(p2_board)
            print(c.cl)
            p2_board, p2_ship_locations = place_cell(p2_board, p1_location, p2_ship_locations)
            display(p2_board)
            print('\nYour Board\n')
            display(p1_board)
            input(c.g + '\nEnd your turn (enter)\n' + c.x)
            #player 2
            input(c.cl + "Player 2, it's your turn (enter to continue)\n")
            display(p1_board)
            print('\nYour Board\n')
            display(p2_board)
            p2_location = pick_cell(p1_board)
            print(c.cl)
            p1_board, p1_ship_locations = place_cell(p1_board, p2_location, p1_ship_locations)
            display(p1_board)
            print('\nYour Board\n')
            display(p2_board)
            input(c.g + '\nEnd your turn (enter)\n' + c.x)



    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(c.cl)
        exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some quick observations just based on the code snippets in your question.

1. Use list comprehension or the `zip()` function:

   ```
   # You can change this:
   x_values = list(map(itemgetter(0), self.coords))
   y_values = list(map(itemgetter(1), self.coords))

   # To this:
   x_values = [self.coords[0] for coord in self.coords]
   y_values = [self.coords[1] for coord in self.coords]

   # Or even better:
   x_values, y_values = zip(*self.coords)
   ```
2. You can store your change directions as a dictionary as well:

   ```
   CHANGE = {
       'LEFT': (-1, 0),
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Why did you do this?

   ```
   side_col = [1,2,3,....]

   # Do this instead:
   side_col = range(1, 31)
   ```
4. Making a board class would be advisable and would help you refactor some common functionality. You could implement bound checking methods in there.

I'll edit this answer as I find more.